# How can I deserialize a json string without knowing the name of the fields?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a string that *can* look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      Id:{  
         editable:false,
         nullable:true
      }
   },
   {  
      Product:{  
         validation:{  
            required:true
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      Cost:{  
         type:"number",
         validation:{  
            required:true
         }
      }
   }
]
```

It can also look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      Id:{  
         editable:false,
         nullable:true
      }
   },
   {  
      Car:{  
         validation:{  
            required:true
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      Make:{  
         validation:{  
            required:true
         }
      }
   }
]
```

The point is that the string will always have an Id field with some predictable values, but additional fields can be named anything.

I have some javascript which I need to look like this:

```
schema: {
   model: {
      id: "Id",
      fields: {
          Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
          Product: { validation: { required: true } },
          Cost: { type: "number", validation: { required: true }}
      }
   }
}
```

... where the content of fields needs to correlate the string.

Currently I have an ajax call that get some other data my code needs and I would like to also give it the results I need for the fields.  I would like to replace the json like so:

```
schema: {
   model: {
      id: "Id",
      fields: ajaxResult.fields
      }
   }
}
```

The normal route is to create a class (or classes) to which I can deserialize the json string, but in this case the fields in the json string can be completely arbitrary.  ***So I cannot create classes for this since I don't know what the properties will be called***.

How can I deserialize this string so when I return it from my Action it will work as I describe?

Currently my controller action looks something like this:

```
public IActionResult GetJsonData(Guid id)
{
   var model = new GridDataModel
   {
       schema = SchemaToJson(id),
       //fields = FieldsToJson(id),
       gridData = RowsToJson(id)
   };
   return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Json.Net?

Comment: Formatted your JSON. Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: What do `SchemaToJson()` and `RowsToJson()` return?

Comment: @timothyclifford I think I'm using Newtonsoft for nearly everything.  The other two functions return Json I need for other areas of javascript code which don't have the same issue (ie, the Json is well defined and has a astatic arrangement of fields).

Comment: @RvdK Hrmm.  Well. I ran it through a validator also and saw what you saw... but I have nearly identical json being handled just fine.  The only difference is that I can deserialize the other json into actual classes (as the fields don't change).

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2015, you can use the "paste special" function, Visual studio will generate all classes (including nested classes etc.) for you, no single line of your own coding is needed:

[image]

See animations below: (original GIF is from [here](http://www.modhul.com/2015/02/visual-studio-paste-special-paste-xml-and-json-as-classes/).)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is cool... but does not appear to address any of the problem in my question.  All this does is save typing.  Typing is not my problem.